# Index of a list of lists in scala

Tags: list, scala, collections, indexing

Can somebody please explain what the following code does? (hyp returns `List[(Int,Int,Set[Int])]` )

```
  def all(): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] = 
  {
       list.zipWithIndex flatMap 
       {
         case (row, r) =>
         row.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 0) map 
         {
            case (col, c) => (r, c,  hyp(r, c))
         }
       }
   }
```

list is defined as a list of lists of integers. I understood that the '==0' is because the method needs to access the elements that are 0 but I don't understand what zipWithIndex does exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zipWithIndex gives a list of (element, index) pairs.

```
val list = List(1,2,3,101,330,302)    

list.zipWithIndex //> List((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (101,3), (330,4), (302,5))
```

so in given example:

```
def all(): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] = 
{
   // if list              = List( list1,      list2,      ...)
   //    list.zipWithIndex = List( (list1, 0), (list2, 1), ...)
   list.zipWithIndex flatMap 
   {
     case (row, r) =>  // it gets (list1, 0) etc.
     // if row          = ( elem0,      elem1,      ...) // list1
     //    rowWithIndex = ( (elem0, 0), (elem1, 1), ...)
     row.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 0) map  // check for elem0 == 0 etc.
     {
        // so col here is cell value, r is row index, c is column index
        case (col, c) => (r, c,  hyp(r, c))   

     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not line-by-line explanation, but I think the key to understanding could be the following:

```
('a' to 'c').zipWithIndex
// Vector((a,0), (b,1), (c,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been watching the questions arrive that are clearly connected with some assignment to write a Sudoku solver, and I've also been doing a kind of 'software development Jeopardy' to work out what the designs are given the questions being posted...

Anyway, my guess is that this function returns the coordinates and possibilities for all unsolved Sudoku cells.